# Does the Java FileDialog work on Mac?

Tags: java, applet, awt, filedialog

I have created a web applet in Java which uses the FileDialog. The file dialog works fine on Windows, I am wondering if it is cross platform. Does it work on Mac and Linux? Or do you need to specify custom parameters? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, FileDialog is part of java.awt.* package which is available on standard Java SE runtime. Mac OSX typically ships with Java SE runtime so you shouldn't have any problem with FileDialog (look and feel might be different)

Comment: Thanks! So I don't need to specify any custom parameters? It would just work normally as if it is under Windows right?

Comment: Java is a "write once - compile once - runs everywhere" platform. When you compile your java code into binaries, it's not run directly on the operating system, but you run it using 'java virtual machine'. Hence as long as your Mac OS has java runtime, your code should run just like any other OS

Comment: So you are saying that Mac supports all code that Windows does?

Comment: It supports "almost all" java code that runs in Windows. If your code do stuff like opening "C:\Documents and Settings\.." then obviously it wont work on Mac

Comment: but if I use System to get the temp directory would work on Mac?

Comment: The issue is that "C:\" is obviously a reference to a windows file system.  Best to keep file references relative if you want them to work cross-platform.

Comment: For temp directory operation, you should always use System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"), this will give you the platform specific system directory. Never hardcode stuff like "C:\Users\Bob\Temp"

Comment: Thanks you've helped so much! Also if you sign your app, java can write to a directory chosen by FileDialog right?

Comment: What do yo mean by "sign your app"? As far as I know you can write to directories all you want.